# Show that $V$ is a vector space when $V$ is the set of all continuous functions $\Bbb{S}^1 \to \Bbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ (which is infinitely dimensional) be the set of all continuous functions $\Bbb{S}^1 \to \Bbb{R}$.
Show that $V$ is a vector space.
Define $\langle-,-\rangle: V\times V\to \Bbb{R}$ by $$\langle f,g\rangle=\dfrac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)g(x)dx.$$

I am very lost on how to even start this problem. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The inner product is *additional structure*, which makes the vector space into an inner product space.  (It's not necessary in order to show that $C(S^1)$ is a vector space.)

Comment: Maybe he even wants to have an inner product space

Answer (score 3):

You must show that $V$ satisfies [the axioms of a (real) vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

As Sammy points out in the comments, the inner product is not relevant to showing that $V$ is a vector space.

---

**Added**: Let us consider a more general question, for a moment. Suppose $X$ is any set, and that $\Bbb K$ is any field, and let $\Bbb K^X$ denote the set of functions $X\to\Bbb K.$ (In the case that $X=\emptyset,$ then $\Bbb K^X$ is the set whose only element is the [empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function).) Given $f,g\in\Bbb K^X$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb K,$ we define addition and scalar multiplication as follows:

- For all $x\in X,$ $(f\oplus g)(x):=f(x)+g(x).$
- For all $x\in X,$ $(\alpha f)(x):=\alpha\cdot f(x).$

It can be shown that for any $f,g\in\Bbb K^X$ and any $\alpha\in K,$ we have $f\oplus g,\alpha f\in\Bbb K^X.$ (This is true even when $X=\emptyset,$ vacuously, since there *are* no $x\in X.$) Since $\Bbb K$ is a field, then one can readily verify that $\Bbb K^X$ (with addition and scalar multiplication defined as above) satisfies all the axioms of a vector space over $\Bbb K$.

Now, in the case that $X$ and $\Bbb K$ have some sort of topological structure on them (so that there is a notion of continuity of functions $\Bbb X\to\Bbb K$), then we can restrict our attention to the subset $V$ of *continuous* functions $X\to\Bbb K.$ All that will remain to verify is that for $f,g\in V$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb K,$ we have $f\oplus g,\alpha f\in V.$ Once we've done that, it will follow that $V$ (with addition and scalar multiplication defined as above) is likewise a vector space over $\Bbb K.$ Your particular case is simply $X=\Bbb S^1$ and $\Bbb K=\Bbb R.$

Comment: People are really downvote happy.

Comment: I've noticed that, myself. I wouldn't really have a problem with it, if people would just say *why* they were downvoting, so I could fix it.

Comment: They come here waiting for a personal class or to copy the whole answer.

Comment: @Sigur I don't know the reasoning behind it but I agree with Cameron that it wouldn't be so bad if they at least provided a reason.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat. Fully agree.

Comment: This answer is totally useless and won't help the OP at all. Your answer consists of something which the OP is certainly aware of and a copy of the comment of Sammy. So I answer: Consider a slight variation: Let $X$ be any nonempty set, and $k$ a field. The set of maps $k^X$ from $X$ to $k$ is a $k$-vector space, given the following v.s. structure: for $f,g\in k^X$ define $f+g$ by $(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$, and $\alpha f$ for $\alpha\in k$ by $(\alpha f)(x):=\alpha f(x)$ (inherited from $k$!). The validity of the axioms follows from the fact that $k$ is a field, e.g. $(-f)(x):=-f(x)$

Comment: @000: That's interesting, considering your (now deleted) comment, recommending that the OP just check that it is a vector space "in the usual way." However, you make a fair point. I will expand my answer to provide some generality.

Comment: Well there is a difference between a comment and an answer, you see. And I am not saying that it's somehow nontrival or whatever, just saying that its useless (as my comment, and this is the reason why I have deleted immediately it). 2 wrongs don't make a right by the way :D

Comment: @000: Answer expanded. (It's worth noting that $X$ doesn't actually have to be non-empty.) Thoughts?

Comment: Indeed, I was aware of that but I thought that this might confuse him. I am very happy to convert the downvote into an upvote; you shouldn't take it personally, I just thought it was cheap. I don't have anything to add, apart from an example of verifying the axioms: $\oplus$ is commutative: for $f,g\in k^X$ we have $(f\oplus g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)=(g\oplus f)(x)$ for all $x\in X$, hence $f\oplus g=g\oplus f$ by definition of $\oplus$ (the point is the third equality, which holds as $k$ is commutative; the first and last equalities hold by definition of $\oplus$).

Comment: @000: Not taken personally at all. Thank you for your prompting and input. My initial take on the problem was that the OP thought that the inner product definition was supposed to play a part in the proof that it was a vector space, and couldn't see how, hence the "cheap" answer.